# An instance of class UITextField was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it.

Tags: uitextfield, key-value-observing, ios7.1

Hello i am getting this error

> An instance 0x18872c0 of class UITextField was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it. Observation info was leaked, and may even become mistakenly attached to some other object. Set a breakpoint on NSKVODeallocateBreak to stop here in the debugger.

I am observing changes made on a textfield in ViewDidLoad

```
    [textNumber addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"text" options:0 context:nil];
```

this responds at here

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object
                    change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {


if (textNumber.text.length==0) {
    [buttonMakeAudioCall setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"off_green_btn.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    buttonMakeAudioCall.userInteractionEnabled=NO;

}else{
    [buttonMakeAudioCall setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"green_btn.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    buttonMakeAudioCall.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
}
```

}

Unfortunately app crashes inside the following method when response comes.

```
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:string];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response,
                                           NSData *data, NSError *connectionError)
 {
     if (data.length > 0 && connectionError == nil)
     {
         NSDictionary *greeting = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                                  options:0


                                                                    error:NULL];

         NSString *balance = [greeting objectForKey:@"balance"];
         NSLog(@"balance is %@",balance);
         labelStatus.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@€",balance];

     }
 }];
```

What i understood is textfield object/observer is released at some point and i need to handle it.But how?I am using ARC.If somebody who knows better could provide more information on the situation,i could handle it.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the reason.It was a mistake from my side.Just before entering this view controller ,I'm calling a method. where I'm writing the following code.

```
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:string];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response,
                                           NSData *data, NSError *connectionError)
 {
     if (data.length > 0 && connectionError == nil)
     {
         NSDictionary *greeting = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data                                                                     options:0                                                      error:NULL];
         NSString *sipserver = [greeting objectForKey:@"ip"];
         NSString *port = [greeting objectForKey:@"port"];
         NSString *control_url = [greeting objectForKey:@"control_url"];
         NSString *version = [greeting objectForKey:@"version"];



         [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
         [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
         [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setBool:YES forKey:@"login"];
```

The problem is this line.

```
         [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Im poping a parent  view controller of the current view controller.Because i've used blocks,this happens like this.Anyhow i found out the solution.This had nothing to do with textfield or key value observer.Hope this answer helps some one .Thanks.